# Keeping a service running during orientation changes

Tags: android

In my application, I have a `Service` which is responsible for looking after a Bluetooth connection to an external device. This `Service` class periodically polls the external Bluetooth device for data and adds that latest data into a log held in cache (or possibly SD card) memory.

Amongst the various `Activity` classes that I have, there is one particular `Activity` that represents the main UI. It is responsible for displaying, in graphical form, the logged data based upon the cache file data. Let's call this `Activity` the `Dashboard`. The user can scroll back and forth on that graph to review the data collected and logged within the cache since the application was started.

For the purpose of this question, there are two modes of operation to consider. It is possible for the user to select a "log to SD card" option, whereby the application must continue the polling and logging to SD card even when all `Activity` classes are killed' (e.g. the user has gone back to the launcher). In this case my `Service` is started using `.startService()` and continues to run, and will only be stopped when the user invokes the application again and disabled SD card logging. The other mode is where the user hasn't selected "log to SD card", in which case the `Service` is still managing the Bluetooth connection, polling and logging to cache memory for the purpose of visually displaying the data on the graph, but only needs to do so while the `Dashboard` `Activity` is being used.

What I have at the moment is that the `Dashboard` `Activity` initially binds to the `Service` using `bindService()`, and does a corresponding call to `unbindService()` within the `onPause()` method (as otherwise I would of course leak the `Service`).

The problem is that the `Service` needs to maintain the Bluetooth connection and continue logging during orientation changes or when the user invokes another `Activity` over the top (e.g. checks an email). Now if the user has selected "log to SD card" resulting in a call to `startService()` then of course there is no problem. The problem of course is how to distinguish between an `Activity` being destroyed and then created again due to orientation (or some other configuration) change, and being destroyed because the user went back to the launcher. In the former case, I don't want the `Service` datalogging to have been interrupted. In the latter case, I want the `Service` to stop, *if* the user hasn't selected "log to SD card".

The best solution I can think of for this at the moment is for the service to be *always* started using `startService()`, so that it continues to run when the `Dashboard` has been destroyed. What I would then do is implement a time-out within the `Service`, whereby the `Service` will stop itself *unless* continuous SD card logging is enabled, **or** the `Dashboard` is `onCreate`d again within five seconds (say) and re-binds to the `Service`. This seems a little crude, and I can't help thinking this must be a common design problem that has a better solution that I've overlooked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach you could use, is check to see if the Activity `isFinishing()` before unbinding in your `onPause()`. If it is finishing, you would defer the unbinding to your `onDestroy()` method. Before `onDestroy()` is called, however, you could persist your ServiceConnection in the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method. If you do perform that persistence, than you wouldn't actually call `unBind()` inside of on your `onDestroy()` at all and simply let the new instance of your Activity do the unbinding.

That being said, depending on your application, you might find it is just easier to start/stop your service.

Comment: Many thanks for this, Justin. I hadn't realised about the `isFinishing()` method (shows I ought to refresh over the `Activity` documentation again). Using the result of this method I am now invoking `startService()` if I know that the `Activity` is being destroyed but is not finishing.

Comment: Just make sure you read the documentation properly. IsFinishing should always be true when your Activity is going to be destroyed. At least that's how i read it.

Comment: will this not cause a runtime error because you are leaking the connection? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308400/what-does-it-mean-to-leak-a-service-connection

Comment: @Sam this answer is pretty out of date and partially misleading. Option 1 that Frido posted is a better laid out answer with all the required steps.

Comment: @JustinBreitfeller thanks for thre reply. If you use this option, haven't you lost some of the advantage of a bound service (that you can bind to it from multiple app components). What if I bound to it from some object that was running a background query AND I bound to it from an activity to do some up front UI IO?

Comment: @Sam In that case, you are going to need a more complicated solution. I haven't done it myself, but I would imagine you would then need to keep track of the number of bind/unbind calls and then use that to determine when to stop your service.

Comment: @JustinBreitfeller I actually ended up asking this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312016/bind-to-service-from-new-context-for-configuration-changes-or-bind-from-app-cont and came up with a potential answer myself.

Answer (score 8):

Option 1: if you want the service to be destroyed, immediately when the main activity is finishing, but not during rotation:

To avoid automatic service stop you must start it manually before binding:

```
protected void onStart() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MServcie.class);
  startService(intent);
  bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Stop the service only if your Activity is finishing!

```
protected void onStop() {
  if (service != null) {
    unbindService(connection);
    service = null;
    if (isFinishing()) {
      stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyServcie.class));
    }
  }
}
```

Option 2: if you want the os to decide when the service is being stopped.

```
protected void onStart() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MServcie.class);
    getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Comment: Should I include their default super call before or after the above codes for onStart() and onStop() respectively? It seems like without super calls included, the app crashes.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`isChangingConfigurations()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isChangingConfigurations%28%29), not `isFinishing()`: the latter is `false` both in the case of an activity that loses visibility and when configuration changes, so you can't distinguish.

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know already, a Service is really for having a separate lifecycle from Activities. As such, you could consider not using a Service for the purely monitoring scenario. You only need a lifecycle separate from Activities in the background case, but not in the purely monitoring case.

What you *really* seem to want is for your logging to be tied to the lifetime of your Application and for you to be able to control the lifetime of your Application through either starting/stopping Activities or your Service. If you did your polling in a separate thread accessible from the Application object, your Activities won't need to bind with a Service at all, but simply communicate with this logging thread. When you do want the background logging, you could start/stop the service which would also communicate with the logging thread to gracefully cleanup on stop, restart correctly, etc.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have accepted Justin's suggestion about using `onFinishing()` as that solved the problem, but your suggestion about putting the polling thread within the Application object is an interesting one, and something I might try. I do already have an object that extends `Application` for the purpose of holding a small amount of global state.