# What does it mean to leak a service connection?

Tags: android, service

I am writing a service for my Android app and I am trying to understand how the binding mechanism works.
If I bind my service in the onCreate of an activity but I don't unbind it in onStop or onDestroy, I get the error :

```
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.ipc.invalidation.ticl.android.AndroidInvalidationService has leaked ServiceConnection com.googl
                              e.ipc.invalidation.external.client.android.service.ServiceBinder$1@4177f8f8 that was originally bound here
```

So my question is : what is the problem exactly with leaking a connection, what am I preventing by unbinding my service ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That happens when Android OS destroys `Activity` and finds that a `ServiceConnection` still bound to a running `Service`, so you need to unbind the service before destroying your `Activity`

Comment: To clarify : the system uses the binding system to know if a service is still used or not. It is especially important if startService is not called, since in that case it is the framework that will kill it, so not unbinding a service when the activity is destroyed prevents the system from doing this efficiently.

Answer (score 48):

Typically your app is the only app that can access your Service (or have a use for it). If destroy your app with this Service still running then that Service no longer has a purpose. It will exist in memory consuming resources but doing nothing. By unbinding or stopping your Service when you are done, you return these resources so that they can be used by other apps.

Think of a child that spreads their toys across a room and then leaves. Everyone else in the house (the parents, siblings and guests) has no use for them and must walk around everything. The toys are simply in the way. If the child puts them away, then anyone can use the room for whatever they want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1! One of the most helpful answers on the topic, especially due to the *great* analogy given!

Comment: but what if I want it to keep running while I am using other activity. I have used START_STICKY in my service to do that but if I unbind my service would stop.. (it is downloading data from a ble device)

Comment: Actually, connections to bound services will automatically be cleaned up when your application process dies. Binder is designed this way to prevent resource leaks since Android can kill your app anytime it does not have an Activity in the started state (onDestroy() may not be called).

Answer (score 4):

The services are still running even after the activity gets closed. So you need to unbind the resource in onStop or onDestroy.